# Show field from belongs_to model in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't get `<%= @line.manufacturer.name %>` to work in my lines views. It's currently throwing up a `undefined method manufacturer` error

Line.rb:

```
class Line < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :manufacturers
  has_ancestry

  def to_param
    slug
  end
end
```

Manufacturer.rb:

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lines

    def to_param
        slug
    end
end
```

In my routes.rb I have both

```
resources :manufacturers do
    collection do
      get :lines
    end
  end
```

and

```
resources :lines do
   collection do
    get :manufacturers
   end
  end
```

I feel like this ought to just work without anything extra in the controller, no? What am I missing? Feel p stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace

```
belongs_to :manufacturers
```

with

```
belongs_to :manufacturer
```

in your `Line` model.

Comment: Amazing! It is so hard to see the simplest things sometimes. Thank you so much.